# Access database records not staying in the right order when displayed in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, visual-studio-2013

Everytime i enter a  new entry in my ms access database in Visual studio, in has now started to put some of the bottom line entries at the top of the database even thought the ID number is in the correct order.

Of course i can get it back in the right order if i click on the id tab, but i also have a chart linked with the database and it is throwing it off.

If i look at the database via ms access 2013 it appears to be fine, if i delete the data and write it again, it still shows up at the top.

Does anyone have any idea on what i can do?

Comment: Database order is irrelevant, use `ORDER BY` in your query instead.

Comment: The order of the data in a database is usually arbitrary, just `ORDER BY` whatever column you want

Comment: I know ı sound like a noob here, but i am, where can i find this?
Do i have to write a new qurey and if so where can i find this

Comment: its saying ORDER BY is not apart of the query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, Microsoft Access (the application) prefers to display the rows in a table ordered by the Primary Key for that table (if one exists). However, that may not be the *natural order* of the rows in the table, which is order in which the rows physically exist in the table (usually, but not always, the order in which the rows have been inserted into the table).

So, if you create a new table with the fields

ID  –  Long Integer, Primary Key
TXT  –  Text(50)

and then insert two rows

```sql
INSERT INTO Table1 (ID, TXT) VALUES (2, 'bar')

INSERT INTO Table1 (ID, TXT) VALUES (1, 'foo')
```

when you open the table in Microsoft Access itself it will likely display the rows as

```
ID  TXT
--  ---
 1  foo
 2  bar
```

because that is the Primary Key order. However, if you perform a query from another application and do not include an ORDER BY clause

```sql
SELECT ID, TXT FROM Table1
```

then the rows will more likely be returned in their natural order, i.e.,

```
ID  TXT
--  ---
 2  bar
 1  foo
```

If you want to ensure that the rows are retrieved in order by ID then you need to include an ORDER BY clause in your query:

```sql
SELECT ID, TXT FROM Table1 ORDER BY ID
```

Comment: Thank you Gord Thompson, I shall give that a try :)

Thank you